# What is the hokey to switch from XAML tab to Design tab in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, hotkeys

I want to know if there's a shortcut/hotkey to switch between XAML to the designer. Doing WPF I like to code XAML full screen then check the design full screen. I've looked up Google, without success.

Something similar to the F7 shortcut to switch between code/design in winform probly exist for wpf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can switch from XAML view to Designer view using SHIFT + F7 hotkey and switch back using navigation.Back (Ctrl + -).

Comment: Please check which hotkey have you got under View -> Designer. It's shift+f7 by default. I've checked on VS 2010 and 2011.

Comment: if you have/use additional tools such as DevExpress, Resharper, etc - they will reset your defaults, so Dmitriy's correct.

Comment: It works perfectly in Visual Studio 2013, also Ctrl + - ...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Open your XAML file in the main view and keep it in the Designer View.

Right click the same XAML file in Solution Explorer and use 'Open With' option.
Select the editor you are most comfortable with from the list of editors.
This opens the XAML mark up code in a separate window.

You can now type the XAML mark up in one window and when you save the changes are reflected in the designer view (open in your main window).

You can switch between them using regular short cut keys to switch between windows in Visual Studio. You can even drag them to different monitors and see them side by side.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question that the OP asked. Using another editor is often not a viable choice and he specifically asked for Visual Studio 2010.